# sbd uses "default phrase to use for encryption"

Tags: encryption, tools

I've been using sbd to compare it with Ncat. Ncat offers SSL with or without certificates. sbd offers `AES-CBC-128`, with an option to override the "default phrase to use for encryption".

```
sbd -h

...

-c on|off   encryption on/off. specify whether you want to use the built-in
            AES-CBC-128 + HMAC-SHA1 encryption implementation (by
            Christophe Devine - http://www.cr0.net:8040/) or not
            default is: -c on
-k secret   override default phrase to use for encryption (secret must be
            shared between client and server)
```

This looks like a default encryption key is hardcoded into sbd. Is this true? If so, would using this default secret make it possible to reverse the distributed binary, find the key, then reassemble TCP streams of sbd sessions and decrypt them?

Comment: `"roses are red, violets are blue."`

Comment: sbd looks more like a backdoor that supports obfuscated communication and not like a serious encrypted transport to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses the default passphrase `"roses are red, violets are blue."` which can be overridden at compile time by defining `SHARED_SECRET` or at runtime using the command line switch you mention in the question.

```
#ifndef SHARED_SECRET
    #define SHARED_SECRET "roses are red, violets are blue."
#endif
```

*from `sbd.c` line 136-138*